# How do I find the unknown C as an unknown denominator and power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried to simplify the equation by isolating C to the other side of the equation. To remove the power C from the left of the equation, I will have to apply root to the power of C to the right of the equation.

How do I solve for such equation?

$4.5 = \frac{1.5}{(1-{\frac{3}{c}})^c}$

$4.5{(1-{\frac{3}{c}})^c} = 1.5$

${(1-{\frac{3}{c}})^c} = \frac{1.5}{4.5}$

${(1-{\frac{3}{c}})^c} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: There is no algebraic method, only numerical methods.

Comment: what do you mean by numerical methods? and how do I know whether this equation can be solved by algebraic or numerical methods?

Comment: For example, Newton's Method. And the way you know is by asking.

Comment: Numerical method means a method that lets you approximate the numeric answer, not express it as an exact formula. So you might be able to find, via a method like bisection or Newton, that c = -0.625 is nearly correct, but there's no nice way to write it in terms of polynomials, or trigonometric functions, or anything else simple like that.

Comment: @ConMan which area of mathematics does numerical method belongs to? pure mathematics?

Comment: According to Wikipedia at least, numerical methods are a part of numerical analysis, which is a school of computational mathematics (since it relates to actually computing values for things rather than just looking at theoretical concepts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to solve $$\left(1-\frac{3}{c}\right)^c=\frac{1}{3}$$ The solution is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) wich is not elementary. To look better, I shall write the result as 
$$c=\Big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{\log (3)}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (3)}{3 \sqrt[3]{3}}\right) \Big]^{-1}\approx -0.624947$$

If,as I suppose, you cannot use Lambert function, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(c)=\left(1-\frac{3}{c}\right)^c-\frac{1}{3}=-0.0833$$ By inspection $f(-1)=-\frac 1 {12}=-0.0833$, $f(-0.5)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{1}{3} =+0.0446$. So, the root is bracketed.

Using Newton method starting at the midpoint of the interval $x_0=-\frac 34$, we shall have the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.750000 \\
 1 & -0.608461 \\
 2 & -0.624661 \\
 3 & -0.624947
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

All the above was rigorous. However, we can approximate the result building around $c=-1$ the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant of $$\left(1-\frac{3}{c}\right)^c-\frac{1}{3}$$ The formula will be explicit. For example, for $n=3$, the *approximate* solution is given by
$$c_{(3)}=-1+\frac{24 (9+14 \log (2) (4 \log (2)-3))}{8 \log (2) (540+146 \log (2) (8 \log(2)-9))-621}=-0.624907$$